# How to run multi Laravel projects on XAMPP or Wamp

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, localhost

I have one laravel project in Xampp and I set my localhost to localhost/laravel/public

and now I want to start another laravel project and now I dont know what should I do.
I created a laravel project in another folder named : blog

but laravel router doesnt work anyway

Comment: Apache virtual hosting: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/

Comment: I cant understand how , I should do it

Comment: You will either do this through routing within one laravel project, or through virtual hosting for two separate projects, basically, you need to learn a bit about Apache as soon as you go beyond one project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use virtual hosts (if you're using Apache) to map different hostnames to different directories on the same server.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

If you're using Nginx, you would use "server blocks"

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are not in the production environment, and trying locally to develop. In this case, you can run the *built-in laravel php server* using the artisan command.

Normal usage.

//run this command inside your folder, in this case inside blog folder.

```
php artisan serv
```

This will start the server on localhost:8000. However, the above command also accept a parameter called port. Run the above command in other laravel project folder with a different port.

```
php artisan serv --port=9000
```

Which will run the server in 9000 port and can be tested using localhost:9000.

If you are using for production purpose, try apache virtual host or nginx virtual host based on your server.

Comment: Yes, this can works, but just is for development environment, NEVER use it for production, in this case use APACHE or NGINX